# Roots of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Considering the following trigonometric equation with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ real and positive.

$$f(x) = \alpha \left(\sin{3x}+\cos{3x}\right) + \left(\alpha + \beta \right)\left(\sin{x}-\cos{x}\right)$$

For given values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the roots ($f(x)=0$) can be found graphically or using a root find numerical method.

I wonder if this equation can be simplified such that it is possible to obtain its roots analytically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the math,

$$ \sin(3x)+ \cos(3x) = (\sin x- \cos x)(-1-2\sin{2x})$$

So

\begin{align}
   f(x) &= \alpha (\sin{3x}+\cos{3x}) + (\alpha + \beta)(\sin{x}-\cos{x}) \\
        &= (\sin x- \cos x)(\beta - 2 \alpha \sin{2x})
\end{align}

So $f(x) = 0$ has roots when $\sin x = \cos x$
and when $\sin{2x} = \dfrac{\beta}{2 \alpha}$

Comment: Nice! thank you very much.